# How do I prevent horizontal auto scroll when viewing Live Metrics?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-monitoring

Within the Azure portal, I have navigated to my function then selected Developer->Monitor->Logs->Open in Live Metrics. This displays the screen shown below.

Frequently, the view automatically horizontally scrolls to the left, to show a black log screen. If you scroll the graphs back into view, it jumps back to the black log screen.

Does anyone know how I can prevent this annoying behaviour? I have tried both Edge and Chrome browsers.

[image]

Comment: did you figure out a solution? I am also really annoyed by this behaviour.  Typically i don't want the graphs/stats.  Most important to me for debugging is the Sample telemetry pane (rhs) and the log (lhs) - if these two panels could fit on the screen together then the annoying auto-scroll to left each heart beat wouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Yes, the answer below is from me. I haven’t used Azure for a long time so can’t recall any further details.

Answer (score 1):

I've found that if you access the graphs via Function -> Investigate -> Live Metrics you get only the graphs without the black log screen so there is no scrolling.

Comment: I am surprised this doesn't have more attention. 

I cannot find your suggested navigation. Is it still valid in the portal? Can you provide a screenshot?

Comment: I think its Home -> All Resources -> select Application Insights entry for your app -> Investigate section on LHS -> Live Metrics. I couldn't repro the original problem (haven't  used Azure for ages) so not totally sure about this.